# How to install ubuntu in a particular drive?

Tags: 12.04

I have created a new partition for ubuntu in windows 7 (L:). Now I want to install ubuntu in that drive only. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can just make some free space for ubuntu in windows and start installing ubuntu.
During the installation select **install ubuntu alongside windows**
[image]
Ubuntu will be installed in the free space created.

Answer (score 0):

at the time of installing Ubuntu in your PC you will come across the following step of selecting partition [image]

Then in that step choose Option No:3 i.e, `Something else`. After that click at continue then you will be continued to

[image]

In this step you can find your partition which you have already given for Ubuntu installation. select it place the mount point as `/` and type as `ext4` and then allocate it be maximum.

hope that helps.